# AWS create instance using 'fog'

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, fog

I am trying to create an AWS instance using rubygem `fog`.
For some reason the bootstrap method just takes too long (more than 10 minutes) and my script times out.
Here is what I am using

```
server = @compute.servers.bootstrap(:key_name => 'mykey',
                                    :username => 'foo',
                                    :flavor_id => flavor_id,
                                    :image_id => image_id,
                                    :subnet_id => "my_subnet_id",
                                    :groups => ["my_security_group"])
server.wait_for { ready? }
```

When I tried to create the instance from AWS CLI and `aws-ruby-sdk` I was able to do that successfully with ease. Just the difference was instead of security group name I had to use security group id.
The fog gem cries if I dont specify `:groups` list and assigns default security group. I am trying to create my instance in a VPC. (FYI)

Answer (score -1):

When creating an instance inside a vpc you need to specify the `:security_group_ids` option (with an array of group ids rather than names) instead of the `:groups` option.

Comment: If I dont specify the `:groups` name `fog` throws error `gems/fog-aws-0.0.8/lib/fog/aws/models/compute/servers.rb:190:in `_setup_bootstrap': undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Smells like a bug to me.  Worth trying newer version of fog-aws before opening an issue

Comment: same with latest version of `fog v1.30.0`

Comment: Yeah, I think if you do the steps within bootstrap directly it should work, but bootstrap itself hasn't been updated yet to match with VPC stuff.